# parse financials from Google Finance (annual /quarterly b/s, i/s, cfs)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, google-finance

I searched over to see if there is any discussion on the getting fundamental data of Google finance, i.e. 3 statements (income statement, balance sheet, and cash flow statements) for quarterly (interim) and annual. Totally 6 set of data. However, mainly only pricing information(such as OHLC, etc is covered, or just saying not covered by API.

What I would like to is to get all these fundamental data and put into mySQL for my future process. I would like the expert here to advice on the best way(s) to get it, by HTMLAgilityPack, string manipulation(instr,mid,etc), LINQ, etc.. ?

I am using VB.NET and mySQL and will consider using php as web interface to get the info from mySQL. Please do give me some concrete idea and example. Thanks a lot.

Below is the link of the html containing, and extract of part of the useful code is followed.

https://www.google.co.uk/finance?q=HKG%3A1300&fstype=ii&ei=jwD8U7m3H8O9lAWUtIDYDQ

```
<table id=fs-table class="gf-table rgt">
<thead><tr><th class="lm lft nwp"> In Thousands of CNY (except for per-share items) </th>
<th  class="rgt"> 6 months ending 2013-06-30 </th>
<th  class="rgt"> 6 months ending 2012-06-30 </th>
<th  class="rgt rm"> 6 months ending 2011-06-30 </th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<!-- 1 row for one coaitem -->
<tr >
<td  class="lft lm bld">Turnover
</td>
<td  class="r bld">1,265,676.00</td>
<td  class="r bld">1,093,939.00</td>
<td  class="r bld rm">876,385.00</td>
</tr>
<tr >
<td  class="lft lm">Interest income
</td>
<td  class="r">-</td>
<td  class="r">-</td>
<td  class="r rm">-</td>
</tr>
<tr >
<td  class="lft lm">Interest expense
</td>
<td  class="r">-</td>
```

Comment: You could change service, some like yahoo offer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api

Comment: Thanks but I hope you could answer to the question that I want is google and how to parse google in different ways. I chose it after considering several sources/services, of which I have considered the timing of update, detail of information and omission of data. Yahoo would not be my choice.